# How to delete the last line of my output file?

Tags: python, hashtable

Been trying to write my PYTHON code but it will always output the file with a blank line at the end. Is there a way to mod my code so it doesn't print out the last blank line.

```
def write_concordance(self, filename):
        """ Write the concordance entries to the output file(filename)
        See sample output files for format."""
        try:
            file_out = open(filename, "w")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            raise FileNotFoundError("File Not Found")
        word_lst = self.concordance_table.get_all_keys() #gets a list of all the words
        word_lst.sort() #orders it
        for i in word_lst:
            ln_num = self.concordance_table.get_value(i) #line number list
            ln_str = "" #string that will be written to file

            for c in ln_num:
                ln_str += " " + str(c) #loads line numbers as a string
            file_out.write(i + ":" + ln_str + "\n")
        file_out.close()
```

[Output_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzLJa.png)
Line 13 in this picture is what I need gone

Comment: Note `\n` in your `file_out.write(i + ":" + ln_str + "\n")`. **You** add line break after ***each*** row.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to delete the last line break in my loop?

Comment: Yes, but much better solution is not to write it in the first place.

Comment: could perhaps give me an idea how to change my overall solution

Comment: My preferred method is to put *new line* ***before*** each line and not do it for the very first line.

Comment: If you are sure that the entire file would fit into the memory then already suggested `join` solution will probably be the cleanest.

Comment: What you are asking for is unusual. It is normal to terminate each line of text with '\n'. Some text editors just display a line number at the and and some don't.

Answer (score 0):

Put in a check so that the new line is not added for the last element of the list:

```
def write_concordance(self, filename):
    """ Write the concordance entries to the output file(filename)
    See sample output files for format."""
    try:
        file_out = open(filename, "w")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError("File Not Found")
    word_lst = self.concordance_table.get_all_keys() #gets a list of all the words
    word_lst.sort() #orders it
    for i in word_lst:
        ln_num = self.concordance_table.get_value(i) #line number list
        ln_str = "" #string that will be written to file

        for c in ln_num:
            ln_str += " " + str(c) #loads line numbers as a string

        file_out.write(i + ":" + ln_str)

        if i != word_lst[-1]:
            file_out.write("\n")
    file_out.close()
```

Comment: unfortunately this printed out a line after every line

Comment: Probably not an issue in this case because `self.concordance_table.get_all_keys()` probably returns an iterable without duplicates, but `if i != word_lst[-1]` would fail in case of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
file_out.write(i + ":" + ln_str + "\n")
```

The `\n` adds a new line.

The way to fix this is to rewrite it slightly:

```
ln_strs = []
for i in word_lst:
   ln_num = self.concordance_table.get_value(i) #line number list
   ln_str = " ".join(ln_num) #string that will be written to file
   ln_strs.append(f"{i} : {ln_str}")
file_out.write('\n'.join(ln_strs))
```

Just btw, you should actually not use `file_out = open()` and `file_out.close()` but `with open() as file_out:`, this way you always close the file and an exception won't leave the file hanging